# Is it possible to use android studio profiler from console?

Tags: linux, android-studio, android-profiler

Is it possible to run profiler from the console, or are there any console equivalents?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is no. But depending on which feature in Android Studio profiler you want to use I maybe able to point you to the right command line tool, e.g. [simpleperf](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/extras/+/master/simpleperf/doc/README.md) for Java/Kotlin method sampling, [Perfetto](https://perfetto.dev/docs/quickstart/android-tracing#recording-a-trace) for System Trace.

Fundamentally Android Studio profiler is a visualization tool, so a command line version isn't going to be very helpful.

Comment: According to the data, you can build graphs, not necessarily on the server. I need this to monitor the application's resource consumption (CPU, Memory, Power). Testing the application version for leaks. 

Now I have a problem with getting battery discharge data in the likeness of data from the powertop utility

Comment: Sounds like you want to have the data for CI/CD purposes. Unfortunately Profilers don't support exposing all the data (CPU, Memory, Power) via command line.

Comment: Yes. For now I'm pulling data from /proc